# Не подключается mongoDB на Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, mongodb

Перестало работать подключение к mongo, пытаюсь переустановить, согласно инструкции: https://ask-ubuntu.ru/questions/602070/kak-udalit-mongodb-i-ustanovit-poslednyuyu-versiyu

На этапе `sudo apt-get update` вылезает ошибка
W: Ошибка GPG: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 9ECBEC467F0CEB10
E: Репозиторий «http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release» не подписан.

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9ECBEC467F0CEB10` Но вообще у тебя сильно старая бубунта, лучше переехать на 20.04